read many ASCII files into R
I have 40+ quarterly ASCII files saved in a sub-folder ASCII in my working directory, they are data from each quarter since 2004, such as DEMO04Q1, DEMO04Q2,..., DEMO24Q1. I want to write a loop to read them into R together. The ASCII files are separated by $.
However, my code doesn't work.
demographics_files <- list.files(path="ASCII", pattern="^DEMO.*\\.txt$")

for (file in demographics_files) {
  lapply(demographics_files, read.delim(sep = "$") )
} 


Try lapply(demographics_files, read.delim, sep = "$") on its own without the for loop.

see also the samples for ?lapply help pages
